# Problems uploading jpg with OneDrive Rest Api

Tags: rest, onedrive

For this HTML5 phone App I have to use the OneDrive REST API.

I managed to upload the file, but the file up on the server is not in .jpg format and won't display in a jpg viewer.  After logging in through the REST API and getting a token back, I used XMLHttpRequest to PUT the file.  I've tried passing it up as an ArrayBuffer and as a base64 encoded string.  In each case the file makes it there, but is not decoded properly.  I figured I needed to tell the webserver how to decode the file with "request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpg')" ,but I get back the following error message from the OneDrive server:

"error": {
      "code": "request_body_invalid_media_type", 
      "message": "The Content-Type header 'text/plain' isn't supported."
   }

```
this.uploadFile = function (token, fileUri,fileName, fileTools, success, fail) {

    var me = app.log('||Microsoft.uploadFile||');

    fileTools.readFileContent(fileUri, 'dataUrl', gotData, fileError);

    function fileError(err) {
        app.logError(me + '::fileError:::' + err);
    }

    function gotData(base64String) {

        var request = new XMLHttpRequest;

        app.log(me + '::token::' + token);

        request.open("PUT", "https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive/files/" + fileName + "?access_token=" + token, true);           
        request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        //request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpg');
        //request.setRequestHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'base64;charset=utf-8');

        request.onload = function (e) {

            app.log(request.responseText);

            success(e);
        };

        request.onerror = function (e) {

            app.log(me + '::7::');

            fail(e.error.message);
        };

        app.log(me + '::8::' + base64String.substr(0,100));

        var b = new Base64Stuff();          

        var aBuffer = b.base64ToBuffer(b.removeBase64jpgHeader(base64String));

        request.send(aBuffer);

        //request.send(base64String);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you still having problems with this ? I may have an answer for you :)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', '');
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: This is what I found working after adding this code. Not sure why it is not an answer.